# Tooltip not working on hover in ng2-charts until developer tool is kept open

Tags: angular, chart.js, linechart, ng2-charts

I am using ng2-charts, line chart in my project. Currently everything is loaded properly except tooltip onhover functionality. When the i hover a particular point and Developer Tool is not opened, the tooltip never appears on screen.
When i open the Developer Tool and hover on the point on line on the cart, the tooltip will appear with proper information.
Below is the code.

```
<canvas baseChart width="400" height="100"
                [datasets]="lineChartData"
                [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                [options]="lineChartOptions"
                [colors]="lineChartColors"
                [legend]="lineChartLegend"
                [chartType]="lineChartType"
                [plugins]="lineChartPlugins"
                (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"></canvas>
```

Typescript code is below

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import {DashboardService} from 'src/app/dashboard/dashboard.service';
  import {Summary,CountryDetails,CountryByDate} from 'src/app/entities/DashboardSummary';
  import { ChartDataSets, ChartOptions,ChartPoint } from 'chart.js';
  import { Color, ChartsModule, Label } from 'ng2-charts';
  import * as pluginAnnotations from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
```

Chart Options and other details

```
public lineChartOptions: (ChartOptions & { annotation: any }) = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      // We use this empty structure as a placeholder for dynamic theming.
      xAxes: [{}],

      yAxes: [
        {
          id: 'y-axis-0',
          position: 'left',
        }
      ]
    },
    annotation: {
      annotations: [
        {
          type: 'line',
          mode: 'vertical',
          scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
          value: 'March',
          borderColor: 'orange',
          borderWidth: 2,
          label: {
            enabled: true,
            fontColor: 'orange',
            content: 'LineAnno'
          }
        },
      ],
    },
  };
public lineChartColors: Color[] = [{}];
  public lineChartLegend = true;
  public lineChartType = 'line';
  public lineChartPlugins = [pluginAnnotations];
```

onHover function

```
public chartHovered({ event, active }: { event: MouseEvent, active: {}[] }): void {
    console.log(event, active);
  }
```

Comment: Sounds like a zorder issue. Set zorder for those things to 10.

Comment: @JohnPeters can you ellaborate please, where to add zorder, i tried to get examples but didn't find any exampl

Comment: Typically on the item that you want to hover over, as shown via F12 Inspect Element in Chrome.  Do you see any specific details about those elements? If you do it's a matter of creating a style with the z-order attribute bumped up.  If there's nothing specific you can style up, then you should find another charting framework.  Or find a way to set a specific html property.